# How to combine NEAR with OR

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, full-text-search

I am using [SQLite FTS5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) feature.

This is the query I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE fts_table MATCH 'NEAR((one OR two) three)';
```

It throw me an error: `fts5: syntax error near "("`.

And then this:

```
SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE fts_table MATCH 'NEAR(one OR two AND three)';
```

The error says: `fts5: syntax error near "OR"`.

Is it possible to combine NEAR with OR? if it is, How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to lift the `OR` out of the `NEAR()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM fts_table
WHERE fts_table MATCH 'NEAR(one three) OR NEAR(two three)';
```